# Laravel - Format JSON

Tags: php, laravel

I have a code that outputs the json result below:

```
{
    "Ghost in the Shell": {
        "id": 1203,
        "Pipeline": {
            "id": 6144,
            "name": "Pipeline",
            "status": "New",
            "item_id": 5962,
            "TotalTasksOpen": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Now how can I format it in the my desired json format below:

Note* I have to remove some result.

```
{
    "Ghost in the Shell": 
    "id": 6144,
    "name": "Pipeline",
    "status": "New",
    "item_id": 5962,
     "TotalTasksOpen": 2
}
```

Will appreciate if anyone can help me please.

Comment: that's not *formatting json*, but *adapting the data structure* the way you need. you just have to change your code before the `json_encode`-bit. we can not help you with that, though, because you haven't **provided said code**.

Comment: (not to mention that your desired format is *not* valid JSON)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your purpose , but here is what you need

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "Ghost in the Shell": {
        "id": 1203,
        "Pipeline": {
            "id": 6144,
            "name": "Pipeline",
            "status": "New",
            "item_id": 5962,
            "TotalTasksOpen": 2
        }
    }
}';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {

    $newArray[$key] = '';
    foreach($value as $k=>$v) {

      if(is_array($v)) {

        $newArray = array_merge($newArray,$v);
      } 
    }
}

$newJson = json_encode($newArray);
echo $newJson;

?>
```